# Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

Tags: php, mysql, xampp

When I try to run my PHP code on localhost, then error given given below appears:

> Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access
> denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO) in
> C:\xampp\htdocs\Final Project CSE-391\project\config.php:2
> Stack trace:
> #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\Final Project CSE-391\project\config.php(2): PDO->__construct('mysql:host=loca...', 'root', '')
> #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\Final Project CSE-391\project\index.php(2): include('C:\xampp\htdocs...')
> #2 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\Final Project CSE-391\project\config.php on line 2

I need suggestion to solve this issue.

Comment: This is a problem to your credential for the mysql. use the credential first directly to the mysql, if it works then you can use it to your php code

Answer (score 1):

This is a wrong credential issue. Check the values you used on the browser to log into `PHPMyAdmin` to ensure it is correct before putting it in the connection config.

You could have entered the wrong password or leaving password to blank after having set a password.

Answer (score 1):

#### Solution

I fixed this by pointing to the SQL port: **`$host = 'localhost:3307'`** instead of `$host='localhost'`.

#### Example

```php
$host = 'localhost:3307';
$db = 'php_crud';
$charset = 'utf8mb4';
$dsn = "mysql:host=$host; dbname=$db; charset=$charset";
$username = 'root';
$password = '1234';
$pdo = new PDO($dsn, $username, $password);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you used a password generator to create your password as I sometimes do.
You may get a password like this: `LJdKE$7swNZ00En2iLwFS3NSvq#`
It will work fine when you use PhpMyAdmin.

If you get an `SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user` ... error.
Then there is a character in your password that PHP does not like.

In my case, it was the '#' at the end of the password.
The solution, change the password.

Answer (score 0):

If the phpMyAdmin port is not the default port, then on the host, it should not only include localhost but also specify the port, for example, localhost:3311.

[image: port phpmyadmin]

example

```
define("HOST", "localhost:3311");
define("USER", "root");
define("PASS", "");
define("DBNAME", "phprestaurant");
```